# How to create two configured instances of the same service?

Tags: grails

I have a service that interacts with a brokerage account's API.  It works fine, but now I need to interact with two different accounts at the same brokerage.

It seems like the best way to handle this is to make it possible to configure the service to specify the target account and then instantiate two different instances, one for each account.

I'm not sure if this is supported in Grails or how to go about it.

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If not, how can I instantiate and configure two different service instances?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Both answers are near misses.  Let me try to clarify:

I didn't want to get into the details, but it may help to explain what I'm after.  I'm using the Interactive Brokers trading API, and they don't let you talk directly to their servers the way other brokerages do.  You have to talk over a socket to their IB Gateway, which is a piece of software they provide that essentially proxies their servers.  So your app talks to IB Gateway, and IB Gateway talks to Interactive Brokers' servers on your app's behalf.

The catch is that IB Gateway has to be logged in to an account as part of its configuration.  So, in order to trade two different accounts, you have no choice but to configure two different IB Gateways, since each can only access the account that it is configured for.

So my Grails code for placing trades must select the right IB Gateway to talk to.  That means it needs to know the IP address and port of the IB Gateway that corresponds to each account.  Other than this setting for IP address and port, there is no difference between the two Grails services that communicate with IB Gateway.

What I want is to reuse the same service class, each being instantiated as a singleton, simply having a different IP address and port on which to communicate.

So making two different services is undesirable, since the code is otherwise identical.  (And if I add a third or fourth IB Gateway, this becomes fairly smelly code.)

And this setting should exist for the life of the application, so I don't think a change in scope is really the answer, either.

I really want two instances of the same service, simply having different configurations.

I hope that helps explain the situation.  What do you suggest?  Thank you!

Comment: When you say service, do you mean Grails Service? And why do you feel it is the best way create new instances of service class for each account instead of using the default `singleton` scope?

Comment: Yes, a Grails Service.  I'm not sure what you mean.  I would expect each Service to be a singleton, running the same code, but with an instance field that contains the account number.  Are you suggesting that the same singleton service would process orders for both accounts?  If so, that won't actually work, because of the way the API is designed.  I need a dedicated service for each account.

Comment: Have a look at the answer and as mentioned by Elias visit [this page](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/services.html#scopedServices) for more details about available service scopes.

Comment: While both answers are informative, neither gets me exactly what I need.  I will update the question.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but why do you always refer "two instances of same service"? The scenario which you have mentioned can be achieved by one service class and in singleton scope. Look for my update I will be compiling in few minutes.

Comment: Have a look at the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the same business logic is applicable for both accounts but taking into consideration that you cannot have a single service class talking to the API for both accounts, then yes you can have 2 service classes (which are nothing but 2 different spring beans) with the default singleton scope.

```
class Account1Service{
}

class Account2Service{
}
```

I would also try if I can use inheritance here in this case, if I have common logic that can be shared across. But keep in mind, if you are inheriting a service class from an abstract class then the abstract class has to be placed in `src/groovy` that is, outside `/grails-app/` to defy Dependency Injection. In that case you might end up with (untested, but you can adhere to DRY concept)

```
// src/groovy
abstract class BrokerageService {
    def populateAccountDetails(Long accountId)
    def checkAccountStatus(Long accountId)
}

//grails-app/services
class Account1Service extends BrokerageService {
    //Implement methods + add logic particular to Account1
    //By default transacitonal
}

class Account2Service extends BrokerageService {
    //Implement methods + add logic particular to Account2
    //By default transacitonal
}
```

Also keep a note that the scope is `singleton`, you would take extra care (better avoid) maintaining global scoped properties in Service class. Try to make as **stateless** as possible. Unless otherwise the situation or the business logic demands to use service level scopes like `session`, `flow` or `request`, I would always stick to the default `singleton` scope.

To answer your second question, you do not need to instantiate any of the grails service class. The container injects appropriate service class (using Spring IoC) when an appropriate nomenclature is used. In the above example, the service classes will automatically be injected if you follow this naming convention in classes where you wan tto use the services:

```
//camelCase lower initial
def account1Service 
def account2Service
```

**UPDATE**
This is in response to the additional information provided by OP.

Referring to the above scenario, there can be only one `service` class in the default `singleton` scope to handle things perfectly. The best part, since you are going out of your network and not really worried about own database transactions the service class can be set to non-transactional. But again it depends on the situations need. Here is how the service class would look like.

```
//grails-app/service
class BrokerageService{

    //Service method to be called from controller or any endpoint
    def callServiceMethod(Long accountId){
        .......
        doSomethingCommonToAllAccounts()
        .........

        def _ibConfig = [:] << lookupIBGatewayConfigForAccount(accountId)
        ........

        //Configure an IB Gateway according to the credentials
        //Call IB Gateway for Account using data got from _ibConfig map
        //Call goes here 
    }

    def doSomethingCommonToAllAccounts(){
        ........
        ........
    }

    def lookupIBGatewayConfigForAccount(accountId){
        def configMap = [:]
        //Here lookup the required IP, account credentials for the provided account
        //If required lookup from database, if you think the list of accounts would grow
        //For example, if account is JPMorgan, get credentials related to JPMorgan

        //put everything in map
        configMap << [ip: "xxx.xx.xx.xxx", port: 80, userName: "Dummy"] //etc

        return configMap
    }
}
```

The scope of the service class is singleton which means there will be only one instance of the class in the heap, which also means that **any class level property (other than methods) will be stateful**. In this case, you only deal with methods which will be stateless and would suffice the purpose. You would get what you need without spending heap or without creating new instances of `BrokerageService` every time a trading happens.

Each trade (with an account assciated) will eventually call the service, lookup the credentials from db (or config properties, or flat files, or properties files) and subsequently configure the IB Gateway and call/talk to the gateway.

Comment: Please see ADDITIONAL INFORMATION added to question.

Answer (score 1):

Grails services are supposed to be [singletons by default](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/services.html#scopedServices), not having any state associated to what it is doing and usually only one instance. Namely, you wouldn't have instance fields in them, normally.

But if you override the default scope, you can have them. For example, you can make your service to be session scoped, adding this static variable:

```
static scope = "session"
```

Then you'll have one instance for each user session.

For your particular case, you may want to take a look at the prototype scope, which will give you a new instance of the service each time you need it injected. You just will have to make sure to always use that instance after it is injected, if you want them to act on the same data.

Take a look at [the docs about Scoped Services](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/services.html#scopedServices).

Comment: Please see ADDITIONAL INFORMATION added to question.